# batch started process locking log file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which calls another batch file that starts a Java server.
The problem is that the java process is somehow locking the file I'm redirecting to on the main batch file.

```
@echo off

code......

echo shut down server
call %serverBin%\server stop worklightServer
rem net stop WLPServer

more code.....

echo start server
call %serverBin%\server start worklightServer
rem net start WLPServer
```

Im starting this batch file with
`E:\IBM\wlp\bin\worklightRestart.bat >> E:\IBM\wlp\bin\restartWorklight.log`

The problem is that this script can only run once, then fails every other time.
It seems that the java process that is start by the `server.bat` is locking the `restartWorklight.log` file.

Not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps the stop/start calls `call %serverBin%\server stop worklightServer` are holding open the exection of the `worklightRestart.bat` that they're called from? Does execution return to this calling batch file? Do you actually only need to jump from one batch file to the other, abandoning the first one - i.e. remove the `call` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the batch file, the stdout stream is redirected. The programs started from inside this process "inherits" this situation so while they are still running, they hold the lock on the file.

The problem is that as the way you are starting batch file needs a lock on the log file, you can not start the process to stop the server. If you place the redirection to the log file in the line where the background process is started, stopping the server will release the lock.

Comment: Is there a way then to log what my batch file is doing without the underlying process locking the log file?

Comment: @tik27. Writing to the log when necessary, not redirecting all the batch file. At least it is necessary that there is no redirection while starting the background process.